# Registering a generic abstract class in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I am trying to register a type by convention, I've simplified my case in this example:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity{}

public class EntityA : BaseEntity{}

public class EntityB : BaseEntity{}

public abstract class BaseClass
{
    //...
}

public abstract class GenericBaseClass<T> : BaseClass where T : BaseEntity
{
    //..
}

public class ConcreteA : GenericBaseClass<EntityA>
{
    //...
}

public class ConcreteB : GenericBaseClass<EntityB>
{
    //...
}
```

I'm trying to find the way to register `GenericBaseClass` to return `ConcreteA` when requesting for `GenericBaseClass<EntityA>`. When trying to resolve this, I get an exception saying something like:

> Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type
>   GenericBaseClass`1, key ""

If I change the definition of `GenericBaseClass<T>` from an abstract class to an interface, this registration code works:

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<BaseClass>()
         .BasedOn(typeof(GenericBaseClass<>))
         .WithService.FirstInterface());
```

However, I need to use an abstract class because I need to write code inside of it.
I can register manually every `ConcreteX` class, but it wouldn't be very helpful.

I've tried with this:

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<BaseClass>()
         .BasedOn(typeof(GenericBaseClass<>))
         .WithService.Base());
```

Debugging, I can see the type is not added to the container.

I am using Castle Windsor 2.6.

Thanks.

Comment: There's no Windsor 2.6. Did you mean 2.5.4?

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<ConcreteA>()
                    .BasedOn(typeof (GenericBaseClass<>))
                    .WithService.Base());
```

If you see types not being added to the container make sure you're scanning the right assembly (the one which contains implementation types, not the service types).

Comment: Couldn't make it work as you suggested. This worked, but I have had to add the same code for any ConcreteX type:  container.Register(
            Component.For(typeof(GenericBaseClass<EntityA>))
            .ImplementedBy(typeof(ConcreteA))
            .Named("ConcreteA")
            );

Comment: Why not? That's exactly what my code is doing (except for the name part)

Comment: @Hero, you solution worked for me, I have one abstract base class and 2 implementations. I had already the same code but was missing the .Named("...") part to differentiate both components registrations using the same service. Thanks!

Comment: @Hero you should answer your own question and vote it up so everyone is aware of it.