# Castle windsor does not inject in base abtract class properties

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a peculiar issue that I have run to. I have two abstract classes that inherit from each other. The one at the base of the hierarchy has some properties that I want to be injected by Castle Windsor. But that doesn't actually happen, when called from a concrete class. Here is the example.

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseClass
{
    public ISomeDependency DependencyNoOne {get;set;}
    protected AbstractBaseClass(bool someBoolean=false)
    {
        //... here I would expect 'DependencyNoOne' to be resolved when
        // called by the concrete class
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractClass: AbstractBaseClass
{
    protected AbstractClass(): base(true) {}
}

public class ConcreteClass : AbstractClass
{
    public ConcreteClass() : base() {}
}
```

Please note that the dependency is resolved in the container propertly, but it seems that since there is no default constructor for `AbstractBaseClass` (? don't actually know, just guessing) the dependencies are not resolved in there as I would expect. There are other `ctor`s in abstact classes that I use in my unit tests that are omitted for brevity.

So, is there a way to solve all this? Should I handle it in a different way? I use Castle Windsor v3.3.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901937/registering-a-generic-abstract-class-in-castle-windsor

Comment: No, unfortunately that doesn't help. But thanks anyways for your time! Learning new things is always good :)